# third party DNS over ISP DNS - privacy issue

Tags: dns

How does using third party DNS like cloudfare 1.1.1.1 DNS helps to protect privacy when ultimately ALL traffics goes through ISP? ISP is the middle man between me and the internet. Since DNS is in plain-text and all traffic goes through ISP, thus they are still able to see the request. Only at HTTPS level they cant see anything at all. Am i missing something?

Comment: With HTTPS, server hostname is still leaked from SNI.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudflare's 1.1.1.1 setup supports [DNS over TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7858) as can be read on [their website](https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/dns-over-tls/), so that traffic can be encrypted and thus not visible to your ISP.

Comment: okay then how about Google DNS or a third party DNS that does not support DNS over TLS. If thats the case, it would be still visible right?

Comment: lastly, by default, DNS over TLS on cloudfare is enabled?

Comment: You're diverging from your original question now. But yes, your ISP can view your DNS traffic if you don't use DNS over TLS. There may be regulations in place which prevent your ISP from inspecting traffic, depeding on the country you live in. If DNS over TLS is preferred is totally dependent on the client which does the queries.